# Can STL algorithms and back_inserter preallocate space?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, stdvector, stl-algorithm

If I have something like:

```
vector<int> longVector = { ... };
vector<int> newVector;
transform(longVector.begin(), longVector.end(), back_inserter(newVector),
          [] (int i) { return i * i; });
```

Would STL be able to preallocate space in `newVector` before processing and adding the new elements? I know it is not a requirement of the algorithm, but would a "good" implementation be able to optimize that? Or, for this kind of case, should I prefer adding `newVector.reserve(longVector.size());` before? I am not necessarily asking whether each stdlib implementation out there does or not (although if someone knows specific examples that would be great), but more whether it is possible at all (and expected), given the interface and requirements of the algorithms.

The question applies to multiple STL algorithms, `transform`, `copy`, `move`, `fill_n`, ... And not just to `back_inserter`, but also `front_inserter` and `inserter` I suppose.

EDIT: For clarity, what I mean is whether a stdlib can provide specific implementations of, for example, `transform`, for the case when the output iterator is a `back_inserter` of a `vector`, in which case it would access the vector object and reserve enough space to store the `distance` between the given pair of iterators before actually running the transformation.

Comment: `reserve` is your friend here.

Comment: `back_insert_iterator` just calls `push_back`, imho.

Comment: Sure it's possible, why not?

Comment: It'd be a pessimization in general case (breaks growth strategy and makes insertion `O(n^2)`). So it's better to stick to just using `reserve` then really necessary (not often).

Comment: @DanM. I imagine it would be implemented by tag-dispatching based on the two iterator types, which is zero runtime cost

Comment: @Caleth what does tag dispatching or iterator types have to do with this? If `add3(vector&)` added 3 elements to a vector "cleverly" reserving space for them, then calling it in a loop would lead to a quadratic behavior since the vector's capacity wouldn't grow exponentially. Same with what you propose. `reserve` is "unsafe" and should be avoided in any place except 1) in the function that created it 2) if you know it won't ever be modified after this.

Comment: @DanM. The idea here would be have a single call to `reserve` per `transform`, at the beginning of the algorithm, based on the distance between the iterators, not multiple calls in a loop. Tag dispatching would be used to "decide" at compile time whether this `reserve` should called. Not sure why `reserve` should be considered "unsafe", though (or "unsafer" than e.g. `push_back`).

Comment: @DanM. `vector::reserve` is allowed to over-allocate. It can choose to keep it's growth strategy despite repeated calls to `reserve`

Comment: @Caleth it is allowed to, doesn't mean it is implemented such way. Relying on this would be bad.

Comment: @jdehesa I've explained why. Or you could refer to the notes here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve

Comment: The problem with `reserve` is that it is not part of a Concept. It would require a very specific specialization, for example of `copy(RandomAccess, RandomAccess, std::back_inserter<std::vector<T>>)`. You can implement it easily; a question (that I have) is exactly where (namespace) to put such function. (Not sure if one is allowed to write it `std::` at all).

Comment: @DanM. we are talking about a hypothetical implementation of the standard library. You are allowed to depend on your own choices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It would require a lot of special-casing in the library, for very little benefit.**

The whole point of separating algorithms from collections is that neither needs to know about the other, and users can add their own algorithms that work with standard collections, or new collections that work with existing algorithms.

Since the only benefit would be to reward programmers who are too lazy to call `reserve()`, I feel it's unlikely that any implementer would implement such a thing.  Especially since it would probably require `std::​distance()` on the input iterators in order to work, further constraining its use.

Note also that such an implementation would need to keep a reference to the owning vector in its iterators, and would be unable to use the most common representation of `std::​vector<T>::​iterator`, namely `T*`.  That's a cost that all users would have to bear, whether or not using this new feature.

Technically possible?  Perhaps, in some cases.  Permitted?  I think so.  Good value-for-effort?  No.

Comment: Yes, as I keep thinking about the question I am reaching the same conclusion. If you are dealing with large collections you should be mindful about performance anyway, and it does not feel adequate to put the responsibility of optimizing every single possible use case on the stdlib vendor.

Comment: The problem is not caused by lazy programmers, but generic code where it is the algorithm not the caller responsible from knowning about the existence of `reserve`. But I agree it would require a very specific specialization, for example of `std::copy(RandomAccess, RandomAccess, std::back_inserter<std::vector<T>>)`.

Comment: Note that it's `newVector`, which is referenced by the `std::back_inserter<std::vector<int>>`, not `longVector`, which provides the `std::vector<int>::iterator`s, that `reserve` would be called on. You'd make a trait to distinguish *OutputIterator*s that can benefit from reservations

Answer (score 3):

You can almost achieve the desired effect of 1 memory allocation using [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html) instead of `std::transform` with `std::back_inserter` .

The problem though is that because `boost::transform_iterator` cannot return a reference to an element it is tagged as `std::input_iterator_tag`. Input iterators are single-pass iterators, unlike other iterator categories, and when passed to `std::vector` range constructor it uses `push_back` to fill the vector.

You can force-restore the original iterator category and achieve the desired effect of 1 memory allocation with a caveat that such an iterator violates the standard requirement that a bidirectional or random-access iterator must return references to elements:

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<class I>
struct original_category_iterator : I {
    using iterator_category = typename std::iterator_traits<typename I::base_type>::iterator_category;
    using I::I;
};

template<class I>
inline original_category_iterator<I> original_category(I i) {
    return {i};
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> longVector = {1,2,3};
    auto f = [](auto i) { return i * i; };
    std::vector<int> newVector(original_category(boost::make_transform_iterator(longVector.begin(), f)),
                               original_category(boost::make_transform_iterator(longVector.end(), f)));
}
```

Comment: The constructor of `std::vector` only needs an `InputIterator`. There's no need to restore anything. Your first version works perfectly well.

Comment: @n.m. `stdlibc++` vector constructor does tag dispatching and uses one allocation for `std::forward_iterator_tag` iterators. I explained that in the second paragraph.

Comment: I have no idea why `stdlibc++` implementation strategies have to do anything with this. The standards says vector constructor needs an InputIterator. Why would `stdlibc++` do anything special for other iterator categories anyway?

Comment: @n.m. To avoid multiple memory allocations. The standard says that the iterator must be an input iterator, you are right. Any iterator is an input iterator, apart from output iterator.

Comment: OK got it, it will work but not with one allocation.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Iterator concepts always confuse me but this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Good news is that range library [does](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/2ebc6f92d3702111fc5cf328f129163d3dfd3765/include/range/v3/action/insert.hpp#L97) reserve for random access iterator containers so if you want you can use it.

Now back to the problem:

**reserve in a loop is problematic**

It is hard to explain without reading [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6snHNLyqk5VAwy18), but if STL algorithm was called in a loop and it was doing the reserve it could trigger quadratic complexity. Problem is that some STL containers reserve exact amount of memory requested(it is understandable for small sizes, but for large ones IMAO this is wrong behavior), so for example if current capacity is 1000 and you call reserve(1005), reserve(1010), reserve(1010) it will cause 3 reallocations(meaning you copied ~1000 elements each time to get place for 5 extra). 
Here is the code, it is a bit long, but I hope you get the idea:

```
#include<vector>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<chrono>
    int main(){
         std::vector<float> vec(10000,1.0f);
         std::vector<std::vector<float>> small_vecs(5000, std::vector<float>(50,2.0f));
         const auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
         for(size_t i = 0; i < small_vecs.size(); i++) {
             // uncomment next line for quadratic complexity
             //vec.reserve(vec.size()+small_vecs[i].size());
             for (size_t j=0; j< small_vecs[i].size(); ++j){
                 vec.push_back(small_vecs[i][j]);
             }
         }
         const auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
         std::cout << "runtime:" <<
             std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t_end - t_start).count()
             << "ms\n";
    }
```

**bonus:**

last time I benchmarked it back_iterator even with reserve was pathetically slow(slowdown measured in x , not %), so if you care about performance make sure that when you use back_inserter your code it is benchmarked against manual loop.

Comment: The benchmark is interesting. In principle, I was thinking of a single call to `transform`, but I understand that frequent calls could harm performance like this. Although, if I am to assume the role of a stdlib developer and decided to implement this feature, I should probably be able to use my `reserve` implementation in a way that is better than just calling `push_back` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it is possible. There is sharp separation from containers and algorithms which work on iterator categories.

Like clear() and erase(), reserve() modifies the container. Introducing reserve(), makes the algorithms container aware, which goes against the clean design of that sharp separation.

Also you could have had

```
deque<int> longDeque = { ... };
deque<int> newDeque;
transform(longDeque.begin(), longDeque.end(), back_inserter(newDeque),
          [] (int i) { return i * i; });
```

or

```
list<int> longList = { ... };
list<int> newList;
transform(longList.begin(), longList.end(), back_inserter(newList),
          [] (int i) { return i * i; });
```

and std::deque & std::list don't support reserve(), yet the code is the same.

One last point: 
vector does not have a push_front() so front_inserter() should not need to be supported.